# How to access HTML5 video tag metadata for Netflix via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I'm wondering if it's possible to access video metadata from Netflix via HTML5 video tag? For example, I'd like to write a chrome extension which could fetch things about the current video being watched, for example: the video title and player offset position.

Does anyone know of any Javascript examples to accomplish this? Specifically, just an example of retrieving the current videos title?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), you will want to do the following:

```
var vid = document.querySelectorAll('video')[0];
vid.pause(); //This will pause the video
vid.play(); //This will play the video again
vid.playbackRate = 2; //This will play the video at double speed

//Get the title
var title = document.querySelector('.player-status-main-title').innerHTML;

//Get the currentProgress
var currentProgressPercent = document.querySelector('.player-scrubber-progress-completed').style.width;
```

I found all of this by simply inspecting the different bits on the DOM. With very little effort, you can easily use a browser extension to scrape this data from a Netflix video and make a nice extension.

If this didn't answer the question, let me know what else you would like to know. I didn't understand what you meant by "player offset position". Let me know.

Comment: Many thanks, I just tried this out, that was easy! What I ment by offset was the position of the video, I found this property provides that: currentTime().

Comment: SO won't let me award the bounty for 24 hours, I just tried it. Will do it when possible, thanks again